# Windows 7 Pro is unable to mount Synology Share

Tags: windows, synology, shares

I have a disconnected lab that has a Synology system for sharing files throughout. We have many Windows XP machines and two Windows 7 laptops. Recently the two Windows 7 laptops were updated and are now unable to browse or map the Synology shares. The Windows XP machines are still able to access the Synology drives and the Windows 7 laptops are able to browse to the Windows XP machines over the network. I am unable to figure out why the Windows 7 machines cannot access the Synology shares, but the Windows XP machines can.

So far I have attempted:

-Rebooting the Synology (DSM 4.0)

-Disabling/Enabling the CIF service on the Synology

-Enabling the WebDAV service (Works using NetDrive2, but not Windows Explorer)

-Rebooted the Windows 7 machines

Since the Windows 7 machines are Professional and not Enterprise, I lack any native NFS support or I would have tried that as well.

Thank you.

Comment: DSM is pretty old... are you able to update to DSM 5.2? Can you access the NAS via IP address with HTTP using a web browser from one of the Windows 7 machines? Have you double checked that Network Discovery is turned on?

Comment: I am able to access the NAS via HTTP and can log in with admin credentials from the Windows 7 machines. The guys in the lab are pretty hesitant about updating the DSM software as they don't have the data backed up anywhere else and the Windows 7 machines worked before they were updated so they feel it's an issue with the Windows 7 machines, not the Synology box.

Comment: On the WIn 7 laptops, try doing a system restore to the state prior to the update(s) to see if the Windows 7 laptops can access the Synology shares?  This will determine if the update(s) have killed access to synology.

Comment: Surprisingly, I reverted the Windows 7 asset to a previous version before patching and it is still unable to mount the share.